# Scratch card game with non-repeat array

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, scratchpad, scratchcard

This is a scratch card game I modify using script from https://jennamolby.com/interactive-scratch-and-win-landing-page-tutorial/ . I was trying to make a scratch card game that plan to use on a e-commerce website promotion. So far I can get the scratch function work. The main problem is now I have set up a array pool contain 3 variables that each shows an image. What I want is the array pool will get empty by splicing it one by one and a function will be execute. I was trying to store the array in json but I not sure whether the script is written correctly. Been confuse for few weeks.

```js
var promoCode = '';
var bg1 = 'https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2020/06/01/22/23/eye-5248678__340.jpg';
var bg2 = 'http://farm5.static.flickr.com/4017/4717107886_dcc1270a65_b.jpg';
var bg3 = 'http://images6.fanpop.com/image/photos/41500000/adorable-puppies-cute-puppies-41538743-590-393.jpg';

var JsonObject, bgArr;

// JS array
var bgArr = [bg1, bg2, bg3];
var json_string = JSON.stringify(bgArr);

var obj = JSON.parse(json_string);

// type
console.log(typeof(JsonObject));

// JsonObject
console.log(JsonObject);


for(var i = bgArr.length-1;i>=0;i--){
  selectBG = bgArr.splice(Math.floor(Math.random()*bgArr.length), 1)[0];
  console.log(selectBG);
}



if (selectBG === bg1) {
  promoCode = 'SCRATCH400';
  
} else if (selectBG === bg2) {
  promoCode = 'SCRATCH500';
  
} else if (selectBG === bg3) {
  promoCode = 'SCRATCH600';
 
} else if (bgArr.length === 0) {
  alert("No more voucher, back to main website");
  window.location = 'https://www.google.com/';
}


$('#promo').wScratchPad({
  // the size of the eraser
  size: 30,
  // the randomized scratch image   
  bg: selectBG,
  // give real-time updates
  realtime: true,
  // The overlay image
  fg: 'https://cdn.glitch.com/2c225b7b-6134-4f2b-9842-1d5d060d9cd4%2Foverlay.png',
  // The cursor (coin) image
  'cursor': 'url("https://cdn.glitch.com/2c225b7b-6134-4f2b-9842-1d5d060d9cd4%2Fcoin1.png") 30 30, default',

  scratchMove: function(e, percent) {
    console.log(percent);
    console.log(promoCode);

    // Show the plain-text promo code and call-to-action when the scratch area is 50% scratched
    if ((percent > 50) && (promoCode != '')) {
        
      $('.promo-container').show();
      $('body').removeClass('not-selectable');
      $('.promo-code').html('Your code is: ' + promoCode);
   
        var audio = new Audio('https://interactive-examples.mdn.mozilla.net/media/cc0-audio/t-rex-roar.mp3');
  audio.play();
        
    }
  }
});
```

```css
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

.scratchpad {
  width: 450px;
  height: 445px;
  border: solid 10px #27cf27;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

body {
  background-image: url("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/32/Googleplex_HQ_%28cropped%29.jpg");
}

.scratch-container {
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  width: 100%;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  .scratchpad {
    width: 400px;
    height: 396px;
  }
  .scratch-container {
    width: 400px !important;
  }
}

/* Custom, iPhone Retina */

@media only screen and (max-width: 320px) {
  .scratchpad {
    width: 290px;
    height: 287px;
  }
  .scratch-container {
    width: 290px !important;
  }
}

.promo-container {
  background: #FFF;
  border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  width: 450px;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', Arial, Sans-serif;
  color: #333;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.btn {
  background: #56CFD2;
  color: #FFF;
  padding: 10px 25px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 15px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: 600;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  border-radius: 3px;
  -moz-border-radius: 3px;
  -webkit-border-radiuss: 3px;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js" integrity="sha256-BbhdlvQf/xTY9gja0Dq3HiwQF8LaCRTXxZKRutelT44=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300,300italic,400italic,600,600italic,700italic,700" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <title>Scratch Card</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="scratch-container">
      <div id="promo" class="scratchpad"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="promo-container" style="display:none;">
      <div class="promo-code"></div>
      <a href="https://www.google.com/" target="_blank" class="btn">Return</a>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      (function(a) {
        'use strict';

        function b(c, d) {
          this.$el = a(c), this.options = d, this.init = !1, this.enabled = !0, this._generate()
        }
        b.prototype = {
          _generate: function() {
            return a.support.canvas ? void(this.canvas = document.createElement('canvas'), this.ctx = this.canvas.getContext('2d'), 'static' === this.$el.css('position') && this.$el.css('position', 'relative'), this.$img = a('<img src=""/>').attr('crossOrigin', '').css({
              position: 'absolute',
              width: '100%',
              height: '100%'
            }), this.$scratchpad = a(this.canvas).css({
              position: 'absolute',
              width: '100%',
              height: '100%'
            }), this.$scratchpad.bindMobileEvents(), this.$scratchpad.mousedown(a.proxy(function(c) {
              return !this.enabled || void(this.canvasOffset = a(this.canvas).offset(), this.scratch = !0, this._scratchFunc(c, 'Down'))
            }, this)).mousemove(a.proxy(function(c) {
              this.scratch && this._scratchFunc(c, 'Move')
            }, this)).mouseup(a.proxy(function(c) {
              this.scratch && (this.scratch = !1, this._scratchFunc(c, 'Up'))
            }, this)), this._setOptions(), this.$el.append(this.$img).append(this.$scratchpad), this.init = !0, this.reset()) : (this.$el.append('Canvas is not supported in this browser.'), !0)
          },
          reset: function() {
            var c = this,
              d = Math.ceil(this.$el.innerWidth()),
              f = Math.ceil(this.$el.innerHeight()),
              g = window.devicePixelRatio || 1;
            this.pixels = d * f, this.$scratchpad.attr('width', d).attr('height', f), this.canvas.setAttribute('width', d * g), this.canvas.setAttribute('height', f * g), this.ctx.scale(g, g), this.pixels = d * g * f * g, this.$img.hide(), this.options.bg && ('#' === this.options.bg.charAt(0) ? this.$el.css('backgroundColor', this.options.bg) : (this.$el.css('backgroundColor', ''), this.$img.attr('src', this.options.bg))), this.options.fg && ('#' === this.options.fg.charAt(0) ? (this.ctx.fillStyle = this.options.fg, this.ctx.beginPath(), this.ctx.rect(0, 0, d, f), this.ctx.fill(), this.$img.show()) : a(new Image).attr('crossOrigin', '').attr('src', this.options.fg).load(function() {
              c.ctx.drawImage(this, 0, 0, d, f), c.$img.show()
            }))
          },
          clear: function() {
            this.ctx.clearRect(0, 0, Math.ceil(this.$el.innerWidth()), Math.ceil(this.$el.innerHeight()))
          },
          enable: function(c) {
            this.enabled = !(!0 !== c)
          },
          destroy: function() {
            this.$el.children().remove(), a.removeData(this.$el, 'wScratchPad')
          },
          _setOptions: function() {
            var c, d;
            for (c in this.options) this.options[c] = this.$el.attr('data-' + c) || this.options[c], d = 'set' + c.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + c.substring(1), this[d] && this[d](this.options[c])
          },
          setBg: function() {
            this.init && this.reset()
          },
          setFg: function() {
            this.setBg()
          },
          setCursor: function(c) {
            this.$el.css('cursor', c)
          },
          _scratchFunc: function(c, d) {
            c.pageX = Math.floor(c.pageX - this.canvasOffset.left), c.pageY = Math.floor(c.pageY - this.canvasOffset.top), this['_scratch' + d](c), (this.options.realtime || 'Up' === d) && this.options['scratch' + d] && this.options['scratch' + d].apply(this, [c, this._scratchPercent()])
          },
          _scratchPercent: function() {
            for (var c = 0, d = this.ctx.getImageData(0, 0, this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height), f = 0, g = d.data.length; f < g; f += 4) 0 === d.data[f] && 0 === d.data[f + 1] && 0 === d.data[f + 2] && 0 === d.data[f + 3] && c++;
            return 100 * (c / this.pixels)
          },
          _scratchDown: function(c) {
            this.ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-out', this.ctx.lineJoin = 'round', this.ctx.lineCap = 'round', this.ctx.strokeStyle = this.options.color, this.ctx.lineWidth = this.options.size, this.ctx.beginPath(), this.ctx.arc(c.pageX, c.pageY, this.options.size / 2, 0, 2 * Math.PI, !0), this.ctx.closePath(), this.ctx.fill(), this.ctx.beginPath(), this.ctx.moveTo(c.pageX, c.pageY)
          },
          _scratchMove: function(c) {
            this.ctx.lineTo(c.pageX, c.pageY), this.ctx.stroke()
          },
          _scratchUp: function() {
            this.ctx.closePath()
          }
        }, a.support.canvas = document.createElement('canvas').getContext, a.fn.wScratchPad = function(c, d) {
          if ('string' == typeof c) {
            var g, h = [],
              j = (void 0 === d ? 'get' : 'set') + c.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + c.substring(1),
              k = function() {
                g.options[c] && (g.options[c] = d), g[j] && g[j].apply(g, [d])
              },
              l = function() {
                return g[j] ? g[j].apply(g, [d]) : g.options[c] ? g.options[c] : void 0
              },
              m = function() {
                g = a.data(this, 'wScratchPad'), g && (g[c] ? g[c].apply(g, [d]) : void 0 === d ? h.push(l()) : k())
              };
            return this.each(m), h.length ? 1 === h.length ? h[0] : h : this
          }
          return c = a.extend({}, a.fn.wScratchPad.defaults, c), this.each(function() {
            var n = a.data(this, 'wScratchPad');
            return n || (n = new b(this, a.extend(!0, {}, c)), a.data(this, 'wScratchPad', n)), n
          })
        }, a.fn.wScratchPad.defaults = {
          size: 5,
          bg: '#cacaca',
          fg: '#6699ff',
          realtime: !0,
          scratchDown: null,
          scratchUp: null,
          scratchMove: null,
          cursor: 'crosshair'
        }, a.fn.bindMobileEvents = function() {
          a(this).on('touchstart touchmove touchend touchcancel', function(c) {
            var d = c.changedTouches || c.originalEvent.targetTouches,
              f = d[0],
              g = '';
            switch (c.type) {
              case 'touchstart':
                g = 'mousedown';
                break;
              case 'touchmove':
                g = 'mousemove', c.preventDefault();
                break;
              case 'touchend':
                g = 'mouseup';
                break;
              default:
                return;
            }
            var h = document.createEvent('MouseEvent');
            h.initMouseEvent(g, !0, !0, window, 1, f.screenX, f.screenY, f.clientX, f.clientY, !1, !1, !1, !1, 0, null), f.target.dispatchEvent(h)
          })
        }
      })(jQuery);

    </script>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? The random array splicing works. What doesn't work is your log, as the variables name is wrong. Log `obj` instead of `JsonObject`.

Comment: Assume that only after 3 different user scratch the card then the array will be empty and a alert function will be call.

Comment: This is what I trying to achieve.

Comment: The game will end after 3 attempt

Comment: how to remain the splicing progress

Comment: @YifoongChan Why you are doing `stringify` and `parse` as you already have an bgArr as an array ? Also the above code will execute for each user browser. Hence, each user will get 3 attempt.

Comment: what I want is each user get 1 attempt.

Comment: Because I doing this for a e-commerce website so I think might need to database or sort.

Comment: @RohìtJíndal consider there are 3 voucher to be give out.

Comment: @YifoongChan *what I want is each user get 1 attempt.* - In this case you have to maintain the voucher at backend. either you can pass only one voucher from the backend or you can send all at once and delete at backend once user accessed.

Comment: More specifically I want the array to splice publicly online.

Comment: So what I need to add?